# Drag & drop audio data from parentNode div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, audio

I'm building a sample pad where users can drag and drop audio snippets onto one of several divs (the sample pad).  When the user selects, drags, and drops the audio, the sample pad should get the audio data.

The audio tags are wrapped inside a parent div.  I'm using jquery and javascript to make things draggable/droppable.  I'm having trouble accessing the audio from the parentNode('#sound_[number]).

**How can I make the entire div draggable, but only transfer the audio data that's inside the div?**

HTML:

```
<!-- sample pad -->
<div id="pad_container">
    <div class="pads" id="pad1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Q</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>W</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>E</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>R</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>P</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>O</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>I</div>
    <div class="pads" id="pad8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)>U</div>
</div>

<!-- sounds from database -->
<div class="sounds" class="small-block-grid-2">
  <ul id="ordered" class="small-block-grid-2">
   <% @sounds.each do |sound| %>  
    <div class="sound_tags ui-widget-content">
      <li class="sound_grid_name">

        <!-- we want just part of the sound name -->
        <%= link_to (truncate sound.sound_name.upcase, length: 8), sound_path(sound), class: "sound_name" %> <a href="#" id="plus_sign">+</a></li>
      <li class="sound_rating" alt="rating"><%= sound.ratings %></li>

      <!-- any user can download sound logged in/out -->
      <li><%= link_to (image_tag "download.svg", class: "download_btn", alt: "download"), download_path(sound.id), :method => :get, class: "download_btn" %>
      </li>

      <!-- user can preview the sound -->
      <li>
        <a class="playback" href="#">
          <%= image_tag "playbutton.svg", class: "play_btn" %>
        </a>
        <%= audio_tag preview_path(sound.id), id: "preview_btn" %>
      </li>

      <!-- user can rate the sound if logged in -->
      <li><%= render partial: 'sounds/rating', locals: {sound: sound} %></li>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div id="view_all"><%= link_to "View All", sounds_path, style: "color: white;" %></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {    
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("audio/mpeg", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("audio/mpeg");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    console.log("Drop success");

  }

  $(function() {

    // add incremental ids to each sound
    $('#ordered div').each(function(i,el){
        el.id = "sound_" + (i+1);
        el.draggable = "true";
        el.ondragstart = "drag(event)";
    });

   $(".playback").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // This next line will get the audio element
     // that is adjacent to the link that was clicked.
     var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
       song.play();
    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ Draggable Jquery library .

Comment: Ok, but how do I call the src from the audio tag when the div is dropped on the sample pad?

Comment: but how do I make the sample pad automatically inherit the data from the audio ID?